# How do I export specifc rows of data to another spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm totally new to VBA and have a requirement to export specific rows based on a value within a specific column to another spreadsheet. Unfortunately I can't post an example so I'll try to explain. I have a sheet that consists of columns A to D and any number of rows. I need to copy all rows that contain [DV] anywhere in column C to another sheet in another spreadsheet.

I have another couple of variants that I would also need to do but I'm hoping if I get this one I can then modify it to suit my needs for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read, each row under the column C (`for each`). At each row you will need to sub string the characters in that cell. `If` they match your condition (DV), than copy it to your desired worksheet.

You didn't provide any code, so this is the best I can help you. If you want more help, you will need to provide some code, and show where it is exactly that you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it :

```
Dim cl As Range
dim wb as workbook
dim ws as worksheet

set wb = workbooks.open("Your other workbook path & name")
set ws = wb.Sheets("destination sheet name")

For Each cl In Range("D1:D" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row)
    If InStr(cl.Offset(0, -1).Value, "[DV]") > 0 Then
        cl.EntireRow.Copy
        ws.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

    End If
Next cl
```